# Enable CORS via Web.config not working for .net WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am trying to get CORS working for my MVC Post action.

I have an MVC attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class AllowCorsJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static String _allowHosts = null;
        public static String AllowHosts
        {
            get
            {
                if(_allowHosts == null)
                {
                    _allowHosts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsAllowHost"] ?? "";
                }
                return _allowHosts;
            }
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
            {
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", AllowHosts);
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            }
#endif
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

To Enable CORS for my web api controllers I do this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
#if DEBUG
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: AllowCorsJsonAttribute.AllowHosts,
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*")
        {
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };
        config.EnableCors(cors);
#endif
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);
        ....
    }
```

I am able to do GET/PUT/etc to my webAPI2 controllers alright. I am able to do Get requests to my MVC controller actions which have the [AllowCorsJson] attribute. However, I am unable to POST to an MVC action as the preflight OPTIONS check keeps failing. The options response has none of the CORS headers in it. It is like my Attribute is not even working for  POST methods.

This get request works when I have the attribute applied to it.

```
    [AllowCorsJson]
    public ActionResult GetExecuteModel(Int32 id)
    {
        var editorModel = GetExecutionModel(id);
        editorModel.UserList = null;
        return Json(editorModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

However POST'ing to this URL fails:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowCorsJson]
    public ActionResult ExecuteSave(MyModel myModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(ModelState);
        }

        UpdateMyModel(myModel);

        return Json(null);
    }
```

For some reason the the my Filter Attribute does not seem to fire when POST'ing to the ExecuteSave function. Why would this be?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Web API 2? You don't need to roll your own, MS have a library that does it, and you can set it to only accept localhost - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: To set to allow localhost only, set the origin like `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*"));` Also, Web API filters are in the System.Web.Http.Filters namespace, not in System.Web.Mvc

Comment: I am using WebAPI 2. And I am using their attribute to enable COR for my web api stuff. It works fine. I had a need to expose an action off of my MVC controller to CORS. (The reason was I wanted to reuse some code from a FORM POST) That is what my question was about. But I gave up making this work. MVC controllers don't seem to respond to the preflight OPTIONS request properly. **The real answer here is to simply create a WebAPI controller for the call, rather than abuse an MVC controller**. (I just refactored so that my MVC and WebAPI controllers used the same code for processing/validating.)

Comment: I know how to make CORS work on webAPI. The question was to make it work on a MVC controller's POST action.

Comment: Is it finding your post action or Is the response coming back but without the CORS headers?

Comment: Have you hosted this somewhere? like Azure Web app?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS in your webapi2 application oby using the following line of code in **WebApiConfig.cs**:

```
 config.EnableCors(allowedApp);
```

Also you need to install the following NUGET package to achieve this:

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of the following

- `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1219", headers: "*", methods: "*"));`
- `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());`